# How can I un-reveal a character's secret?

Tags: character-creation, modern-age-rpg

My gaming group just started a new RPG campaign, set in futuristic space using Modern Age 0.991 rules. Our campaigns have typically lasted 1-2 years each, so serious thought goes into each of my characters.

My new character is a mercenary. One concept for my character was going to be a branding crisis--he would give himself a new moniker/alter-ego (AfterShock, Grimstone, etc.) each week. The group was not going to know his real name until months later, where maybe when he was vulnerable he would tell them--and only them--his real name. It could have been a really interesting character development, letting his guard down and accepting his crew.

But I ruined it when I revealed his real name on the first night. I was also excited about his real name, and when someone asked offhand I just told them without thinking it through. Then of course they told the rest of the party. The rest of the time they addressed me by his real name, not his self-given moniker.

So my question is: should I still try to introduce the rebranding concept with this character, or save it for a different character in another campaign? How could ask the party to forget my real name? Note that my character has many other fun traits to explore, not just this rebranding idea, so it's not a total loss to play without it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We need to know which game system you are playing as some RPGs may have rules to cover this situation. Please [edit] your question to add a tag for what game you are playing.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't speak to your fellow players about it?

Comment: Yeah I've decided that's what I'll do. I wanted to keep it a secret from the players too, but now I'll try to see if it works with just their characters.